# .NET Date Add Days

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datetime, datetime-format

I have date in this format "1999-05-31T13:20:00.000-05:00" I want to add some hours or days to it . Can some one suggest how to do that with this format and AddDays or AddHours ? Result need to return same format.

Comment: Congrats on using ISO8601 :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using `DateTimeOffset.Parse`. Then use `AddDays` or `AddHours`.

It is important to use DateTimeOffset instead of DateTime if you want to preserve the same timezone offset that you parsed.

```
var dateTimeOffset = DateTimeOffset.Parse("1999-05-31T13:20:00.000-05:00");
var newDateTimeOffset = dateTimeOffset.AddHours(1);
var newDateTimeString = newDateTimeOffset.ToString("O");
```

if you don't like the way "O" formats, you can use this:

```
var newDateTimeString = newDateTimeOffset.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fffK")
```

This will 100% match to your format.

Comment: After adding days to it datefomat was changed can it stay in same format ?

Comment: @user608576 - You can use ToString() to convert to a string with any format.

Answer (score 2):

Example:

```
txt_del.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
/* for date picking textbox*/

double d2 = double.Parse(txt_till.Text);
/*second textbox for number of days to add*/

DateTime  tom = Calendar1.SelectedDate.AddDays(d2);
/*for adding number of days to selected date*/

txt_total.Text = tom.ToString("MM/dd/yy")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateTime.Parse(...)` to create a `DateTime` object.  Then you can add days and/or hours, and then `ToString()` to get the new string.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like datetimeoffset. Perhaps from sql server?  You should be able to use the datetimeoffset structure and the parse method.  Once you have a datetimeoffset type you can use addhours or related methods.